# Compare headers of two FASTA files in R

Tags: r, bioinformatics, fasta

I have two FASTA files with approximately 8500 protein headers. I want to compare these two files and point out the differences between them.
till now I have tried the diffr package. but it is not working as required.

```
library(diffr)
diffr(Myxo_greped.txt, Myxo_arranged_final.txt)
```

The picture shows how my two files look at first glance.

[image]

Comment: There is also another R package that compares objects - [diffobj](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/diffobj/vignettes/diffobj.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using *bash*:

```
diff <(grep ">" file1.fasta) <(grep ">" file2.fasta)
```

Using *R*:

```
# read the files
f1 <- readLines("file1.fasta")
f2 <- readLines("file2.fasta")

# join the headers side by side
f12 <- cbind(f1 = grep(">", f1, value = TRUE), 
             f2 = grep(">", f2, value = TRUE)) 

# extract rows that are different
f12[ f1 != f2, ]
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you need to put the file names in quotes:

This is the example fasta file:

```
writeLines(">p1\nKLCLYTHI\n>p3\nGRNIYYGSY","file1.fa")
writeLines(">p1\nLYSETWNT\n>p4\nGIMLLLITMATAFM","file2.fa")
```

And we read:

```
library(diffr)
diffr("file1.fa","file2.fa")
```

If you want to know difference in headers:

```
library(Biostrings)
f1 = readAAStringSet("file1.fa")
f2 = readAAStringSet("file2.fa")

> names(f1)
[1] "p1" "p3"
> names(f2)
[1] "p1" "p4"

> setdiff(names(f1),names(f2))
[1] "p3"
> intersect(names(f1),names(f2))
[1] "p1"
```

Comment: what if i want to view just the headers that are different?

Comment: i have 8492 headers in both

Comment: and.. you want to know say what is present in file 1 and not in file 2?

Comment: exactly. i just want to view the differences (if any)

Comment: you just use readLines. Above i used something from Biostrings. It's more geared towards parsing fasta files